# Django -- Order by Date (Desc) but Leave Selected Items At End

Tags: django

Can't get my head around how to do this in Django (or if its possible) but figured I'd ask.

I would like to sort my items from my model by date with most recent items listed first.

BUT, I would also like to have any items marked as `EXPIRED=True` to go to the end of the list, regardless of date posted.

Thus the order might look something like this.

```
Item A    Date: Today  Expired: False
Item B    Date: Yesterday   Expired: False
Item C    Date:  Today    Expired: True
Item D    Date: Yesterday Expired: True
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Item.objects.order_by('-Expired','-Date')`